External Monitor Flickers When Windows Tries to Turn It Off After Idle
I’m experiencing an issue with my Dell Latitude E7470 (Intel i7-6600U, Intel HD Graphics 520) connected to an LG UltraGear monitor via HDMI on Windows 11. After a few minutes of inactivity, both my internal and external screens turn black momentarily, and Windows plays a sound as if it’s detecting the external monitor again. This flickering happens regularly and appears tied to the screen timeout settings. Here are the key points I’ve identified:

No issue in Ubuntu: The external screen works perfectly without flickering when I boot into Ubuntu.
No flickering with a different monitor: When I connect the computer to a different external monitor, the flickering stops.
Tied to screen timeout settings: If I set Windows to turn off the screen after 1 minute of idle time, the flickering happens exactly 1 minute after I stop using the computer. Adjusting the timeout to 2 minutes causes the flickering to happen every 2 minutes.
Driver updates attempted: I have reinstalled the latest drivers for my CPU and GPU from Intel’s official website, but the issue persists.

Given that the problem only occurs in Windows 11 with this specific external monitor, it seems to be a software or driver-related issue. How can I fix this flickering issue?

Have you tried changing the refresh rate of the external display?

I tried to set both screens on the lowest refresh rate available. I don't see any change in the behavior. However, I made some more tests and I now believe Windows tries and fails to turn off the screen after x minutes of inactivity, which causes the flickering. I updated the question accordingly
